# TCL/TK Text command always shows the last input line

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I just want to figure out how to insert the contents of a variable through `.txt insert end $var` and have what I have inserted be displayed always in the last line automatically, without needing to scroll down the text manually.

A simple TCL example:

```
proc push_button { } {
    global k
    set name [.ent get]
    .txt insert end "$k New Line...$name\n"
}
global k
set k 1
frame .frm -relief groove
label .lab -text "Enter name:"
entry .ent
button .but -text "Insert Line" -command "push_button; incr k"
text .txt -width 20 -height 10
pack .lab -in .frm
pack .ent -in .frm
pack .frm
pack .but
pack .txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `.txt see end` to make the index `end` visible. To avoid getting a blank line at the bottom you might want to use `.txt see end-2c` which makes the character before your last `\n` visible. `end-2l` would work too (`c` = chars, `l` = lines, you need `2` because the widget adds an extra newline after the last character you insert in it). You do this every time you have added text to the widget.

For example:

```
proc push_button { } {
    global k
    set name [.ent get]
    .txt insert end "$k New Line...$name\n"
    .txt see end-2c
}
```

Documentation: [global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [text](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm)

Comment: Hi Peter...sorry I couldn't  capture your idea. Could you send me some new lines of the example above? tks

Comment: @Felipe: example added.